# R dropbox auth on Ubuntu

Tags: r, dropbox-api, rcurl

I'm trying to download files from my Dropbox account using rdrop2 package.
almost immediately after clicking "allow" 
[image]

I get an error:

[image]

session info, may be it will handful for someone:
[image]

I get the same error with `twitteR` package.

On my PC everything worked perfectly. There is no proxy...

Comment: Maybe you need a proxy. Sounds like a network issue. Can you curl anything from R?

Answer (score 0):

thank you for considering. Seems to be i've found a partial solution for this case. After i've connected via mobile phone (share point) the error disappeared. Definitely something wrong with network. Keep trying to find out what it is.